# iAd banner doesn't flip with device orientation

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, orientation, device, iad

My Device orientation is set to Portrait and upside down. On device and simulator when I click on ad banner in Portrait, ad loads in Portrait. However, when I flip the device to upside down, the app flips upside down but the iAd doesn't and stays at portrait. So in other words the upside down app, iAd is not viewable upside down. How do I make the iAd flip to be viewable with the upside down orientation app?

I used the following to make device orientation upside down and portrait. But how do I do this for the iAd now?

```
 -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);

}
```

I added iAd on top of storyboard screen with following code...

```
 -(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

[banner setAlpha:1];

[UIView commitAnimations];
 }
```

Comment: How is the iAd added to the screen - in code or via Storyboard? Off the top of my head it sounds like the iAd is not in the object graph and so is not receiving interface orientation messages.

Comment: I added iAd banner on top of screen in storyboards with the edited code in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point you can only program iAd banner's device orientation to portrait and landscape. No upside-down orientation for iAd and I believe AdMob banners are the same.